# decompose a tupple in a comprehension list

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

I have a dictionary where the keys are tuples. I'm looking for a comprehension list to decompose the tuples in a list

```
dicto={(1,2):1, (3,4):1, (5,6):3}
expected outcome: [1,2,3,4,5,6] (order doesnt matter)
```

The best I came up so far is :

```
[x for x, y in dicto.keys()] ### [x, y for x, y in dicto.keys()] doesnt work :-(
```

Is there a nice and elegant way to achieve that in a single line ?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You flatten `dicto.keys()` by using a single comprehension:

```
dicto={(1,2):1, (3,4):1, (5,6):3}
final_result = [i for b in dicto.keys() for i in b]
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 5, 6, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 4):

You can fetch all keys of your `dict`, flatten it with [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain)to get your desired result

```
>>> import itertools
>>> dicto={(1,2):1, (3,4):1, (5,6):3}
>>> list(itertools.chain(*dicto.keys()))
>>> [1, 2, 5, 6, 3, 4]
```

Alternatively you can also use [`itertools.chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) to flatten your nested list of tuples (dict keys)

```
>>> import itertools
>>> dicto={(1,2):1, (3,4):1, (5,6):3}
>>> list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(dicto.keys()))
>>> [1, 2, 5, 6, 3, 4]
```

Comment: Good answer. There's `list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(dicto.keys()))` too.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the reduce function to combine the lists:

```
dicto = {(1,2):1, (3,4):1, (5,6):3}
your_list = list(reduce(lambda a, b: a + b, dicto.keys()))
```